# Combining all features into one in same shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, features

I am creating fiber routes on a CAD drawing and need to merge the features in the same shapefile. Application websites will not allow me to upload because it has several line features. I need every polyline (33 in this shp) to combine as one feature. Basically, the attribute table should show only one feature. Since I drew it in AutoCAD, it has no field value to merge in a table. Is there any tool to help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Dissolve tool (leave dissolve attribute blank)

OR

you can select all features and select merge with digitizing tools

Comment: Additionally, CAD data is notorious for having small errors in it, so make sur to check validity and Fix Geometries afterwards.

Comment: Hey this worked thanks!